# compute x for a cubic congruence equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

For $x^3 = 123456789 \pmod{1000000007}$ given $1000000007$ is a prime. Find $x$.

My school only teach us about linear congruence equation, and it is an extra credit question. Therefore, I think the question can solve by using the concept only in linear congruence equation.

Original, for $ax = b \pmod{k}$, i usually would do a extended euclid algorithm. However, in this case, seem the algorithm cannot be apply.

Can anyone give me some helps??

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By Fermat's Theorem, since (we are given that) $1000000007$ is prime,

$123456789^{1000000006}\equiv 1 \pmod{1000000007}$, and so also

$123456789^{1000000007}\equiv 123456789 \pmod{1000000007}$.

With some manipulation, this should allow you to find a power of $123456789$ that cubes to $123456789$.